# Can I finely control logging by Corda nodes

Tags: corda

How can I control logging from corda nodes better? Is the log4j2.xml file the only place? Can I, for instance, only turn off the `I 15:37:04 89 NodeVaultService._queryBy - Vault Query for contract type: etc` messages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot turn off specific messages, but your node's logging configuration file can specify the level each class should print messages at. For example, you could specify that the `net.corda.node.services.vault.NodeVaultService` class should only print messages that are `WARN` or above, which would filter out the message above (as well as any other `INFO`-level messages from the `NodeVaultService`.

You can find instructions on how to perform this filtering here: [How to stop node from logging node.conf during startup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52305928/how-to-stop-node-from-logging-node-conf-during-startup).

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Joel's answer.

If you're launching using runnodes, you can pass logging level parameters through Gradle using "logging-level=DEBUG".

As well as 'DEBUG', you can pass in ERROR, WARN, INFO, DEBUG, TRACE (ascending order of verbosity)

Answer (score 1):

So the runnodes command is
./runnodes --logging-level=DEBUG

BTW, if starting the node with corda.jar, we can set the logging level as follows -
java -jar corda.jar --logging-level=DEBUG

\Sean