# How to log the SQL being run by the node in VaultService?

Tags: corda

I would like to see in the log the SQLs that are being run when `.queryBy` is used. How do I go about adding this into the log4j xml to increase the visibility i.e debug level?

I have the the log below in my xml file.

```
<Loggers>
   <Root level=“info”>
       <AppenderRef ref=“Console-Appender”/>
       <AppenderRef ref=“RollingFile-Appender”/>
   </Root>
   <Logger name=“net.corda” level=“trace” additivity=“false”>
       <AppenderRef ref=“Console-Appender”/>
       <AppenderRef ref=“RollingFile-Appender”/>
   </Logger>
<Logger name=“net.corda.node.services.config.ConfigHelper” level=“warn” additivity=“false”>
       <AppenderRef ref=“Console”/>
</Logger>
       <Logger name=“org.hibernate.SQL” level=“trace” additivity=“false”>
           <AppenderRef ref=“Console-Appender”/>
       </Logger>
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct syntax, in either the node's log4j2.xml or log4j2-test.xml (for tests), is to set the level to **debug** as per:

```
    <Logger name="org.hibernate.SQL" level="debug" additivity="false">
        <AppenderRef ref="Console-Appender"/>
        <AppenderRef ref="RollingFile-Appender"/>
    </Logger>
```

Please ensure you are modifying the correct log4j2.xml file.

Comment: This is correct. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52305928/how-to-stop-node-from-logging-node-conf-during-startup for an example of a logging configuration file you can add this block to and instructions on getting your node to pick it up.

Answer (score 0):

If the results your were expecting do not match actual returned query results you can add an entry to your log4j2.xml configuration file to enable display of executed SQL statements:

```
<Logger name="org.hibernate.SQL" level="debug" additivity="false">

    <AppenderRef ref="Console-Appender"/>

</Logger>
```

You'll need to change it in `log4j2-test.xml` too if you're running against unit tests.

Comment: Added my log xml in the question as example. Its not working still.